# Parallel execution with maven-surefire-plugin is throwing PluginResolutionException

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin, parallel-execution

I am trying to execute my feature files via TestRunner.java files (by mentioning them in pom.xml) , in parallel using maven-surefire-plugin, for which i have set up pom.xml as below, but when i run pom.xml as maven test, its throwing PluginResolutionException when the version is 3.0.0-M3, when i have update the version to 2.19.1, the maven test is not running my feature files but the build is shown as successful

- I have tried with different versions but not worked
- Also I have tried replacing the configuration part with below changes

still  my feature files are not executed but the build is 
   successful

```
<configuration>
<forkCount>3</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
<!-- 
<parallel>classes</parallel>
<forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
<threadCount>3</threadCount>
-->
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
<includes>
<include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
</includes>
</configuration>
```

PS: After reading the below  artical
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Running_tests_in_parallel

I understand that there is link between the Junit version and surefireflugin i use in my project, bow one thing is for sure, the correct combination of Junit and maven-surefire-plugin is very much necessary, i have tried with below combinations

```
JUnit 4.7
plugin 3.0.0-M3

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
<artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin> 

JUnit 4.12
plugin 2.20

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.20</version>
<configuration>
<parallel>classes</parallel>
<threadCount>3</threadCount>
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
<includes>
<include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
</includes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

but its not helpful, I suppose i am doing mistake in choosing this versions and the config of plugin with proper parameters, please help me

My complete pom is as below

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.practise.raja</groupId>
            <artifactId>SeleniumConcepts</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.12</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.3</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\javac</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>classes</parallel>
                            <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
                            <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```

Expected: 
My feature files should run in parallel
Actual:
My feature files are not executed

[image]

After changing the dependencies and plugin as suggested by sureshmani, this is how it looks
[image]

Comment: You are using cucumber 4 which offers parallel execution as a option. I think using that option is a better way to achive parralel execution rather than rely on surefire plugin.

Comment: This is my practice program, for my project we are use cucumber 3.X.X version, to implement parallel programming there,  we will need to use the above configurations, please suggest how should i choose the versions.

Comment: @Sureshmani The cucumber jvm parallel plugin is no longer supported as mentioned in the git hub page https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin, also the last update was on April 2018, i understand that its working right now, but for a longer need what should i choose to use. Please suggest

Comment: I would suggest to migrate towards cucumber 4. There is excellent doc here - https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

Comment: @Sureshmani, i have tried as mentioned in the link,unfortunately, its not working for me, not sure where i am doing mistake, top of it, after the changes , my test runner file shows all run options as stroked off as if they are not supported or deprecated   , please refer to the screen shot attached above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve this, to my initial pom,  have started doing below changes. Which ran my feature files in parallel

Change 1: I happen to add the dependency for cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin along with plugin ,so i have deleted the plugin

Change 2: I have realized that the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin is not able to recognize the feature files when I have them placed src/main/java , some of the posts said i have to move all feature files to src/main/resources/feature , where features is package

Change 3: I have realized that cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin is not able to recognize the resources like step def's and drivers etc, so i have used build-helper-maven-plugin where i have declared the resources as below

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>add-source</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>add-source</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<sources>
<source>src/main/java/</source>
<source>src/main/resources/</source>
<source>features</source>
</sources>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Change 4: cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin in the maven life cycle in my IDE, because for some reason maven is not able to consider this plugin in it execution
Eclipse --> Windoes --> Preferences --> Maven->LifeCycleMappings-> copy paste below code

```
<pluginExecution>
<pluginExecutionFilter>
<groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
<goals>
<goal>generateRunners</goal>
</goals>
<versionRange>[4.2.0,)</versionRange>
</pluginExecutionFilter>
<action>
<ignore/>
</action>
</pluginExecution>
Then , click on "Reload workspace lifecycle mapping metadata" button in Preference 
Maven modal

My final pom looks like this
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.practise.raja</groupId>
<artifactId>JUnitCucumberParallelExecutionPractise</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>JUnitCucumberParallelExecutionPractise</name>
<description>JUnitCucumberParallelExecutionPractise</description>
<dependencies>
<!--        <dependency>
<groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
-->
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>4.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
<version>4.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
<src.main.java>src/main/java</src.main.java>
</properties>
<build>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>${src.main.java}</directory>
</resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>add-source</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>add-source</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<sources>
<source>src/main/java/</source>
<source>src/main/resources/</source>
<source>features</source>
</sources>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\javac</executable>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
<version> 4.2.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>generateRunners</id>
<phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>generateRunners</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<featuresDirectory>src/main/resources/features</featuresDirectory>
<glue>
<package>com.qa.stepdef</package>
</glue>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test- 
sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
<cucumberOutputDir>${project.build.directory}</cucumberOutputDir>
<format> json </format>
<strict>true</strict>
<monochrome>false</monochrome>
<useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
<namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
<namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
<parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<!-- Specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a path 
relative to the project base directory) -->
<!-- <customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/custom-runner-template.java.vm 
</customVmTemplate> -->
<!-- Specify a custom package name for generated sources. Default is no 
package. -->
<!--<packageName></packageName> <plugins> <plugin> <name>json</name> 
</plugin> 
<plugin> <name>html</name> </plugin> <plugin> <name>pretty</name> </plugin> 
</plugins> -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.20</version>
<configuration>
<forkCount>3</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
<includes>
<include>**/*IT.class</include>
</includes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>

Even after these changes, an error started showing at <execution> in pom, it says 
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.github.temyers:cucumber- 
jvm-parallel-plugin:4.2.0:generateRunners (execution: generateRunners, phase: 
generate-

But, its fine, i am able to run the feature files in parallel even with this above 
error
```

test-sources)